# PHP date format from a very strange saved datetime string

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

I have a date time string saved in DB as `20230829130000`
and in actuality this string means: **2023-08-29 13:00:00**

I want it to be formatted properly like this: **August 22, 2023, 1:00 pm**

Is there any PHP function to format the date from this string or do I need to break the string and then format it?

Comment: `date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime("20230829130000"))`

Comment: Works like a charm... can you post it as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DateTime object for this.

```
$inputString = '20230829130000';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $inputString);
$formattedDate = $dateTime->format('F j, Y, g:i a');

echo $formattedDate; // Output: August 29, 2023, 1:00 pm
```

Comment: This is correct but the comment in my question is doing the same thing but with less code.

Comment: @Omer It's not the same thing, but it is similar. Using `strtotime()` is a more limited solution because you cannot specify what the date format is, and it can have a hard time with some date formats. Using DateTime is also more readable and it is more understandable what it is doing. Both work though in your case.

Comment: @Omer Also, my solution can be written in 1 line as well, e.g `DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '20230829130000')->format('F j, Y, g:i a')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `strtotime` to convert it to a timestamp. Then use the Date function and pass it variables to output the proper format.

`date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime("20230829130000"))`